# Combining consecutive date period

Tags: c#, date

I have a date period list and those period doesn't overlap

```
|StartDate| EndDate|
| null    |  1/12  |
| 2/12    |  null  |
| null    |  4/12  |
| 6/12    |  8/12  |
| 9/12    |  null  |
| null    |  10/12 |
| 11/12   |  null  |
```

I have to combine those period to a list shown as following:

```
|StartDate| EndDate|
| null    |  1/12  |
| 2/12    |  4/12  |
| 6/12    |  8/12  |
| 9/12    |  10/12 |
| 11/12   |  null  |
```

Here is my solution but I think it is not a smart way

```
        var dateList = periodList.SelectMany(x => new[] { 
            new {Date = x.Item1, type = "S"}, 
            new {Date = x.Item2, type = "E"} 
        }).Where(x => x.Date != null).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToArray();

        var result = new List<Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>>();
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            if (i == 0 && dateList[i].type == "E")
            {
                result.Add(new Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>(null, dateList[i].Date));
            }
            else if (i + 1 == dateList.Count() && dateList[i].type == "S")
            {
                result.Add(new Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>(dateList[i].Date, null));
            }
            else
            {
                if (dateList[i].type == "S" && dateList[i+1].type == "E")
                {
                    result.Add(new Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>(dateList[i].Date, dateList[i + 1].Date));
                    i++;
                }                    
            }
            i++;
        } while (i < dateList.Count());
```

Comment: I suggest you to create some `DateRange` class with properties `StartDate` and `EndDate` instead of using Tuple with meaningless `Item1` and `Item2` properties. You also can create methods like `Intersects` to check if time ranges intersect and method `Intersetion` to get new time range from two ranges.

Comment: are the dates in your input list in order (i.e. a larger EndDate never comes before a smaller one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution may seem **longer**, but it is **cleaner** *in my opinion*. I consider that you have **Period** class (instead of `Tuple<DateTime?, DateTime?>`) as below:

```
public class Period
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Add your dates to list of *Periods*:

```
// Make list of periods ready
List<Period> periodList = //Prepare periods;
```

Get start dates and end dates *separately* by *eliminating* **null** ones:

```
// Get start dates
List<DateTime> startDates = periodList
    .Where(p => p.StartDate.HasValue)
    .Select(p => p.StartDate.Value)
    .ToList();

// Get end dates
List<DateTime> endDates = periodList
    .Where(p => p.EndDate.HasValue)
    .Select(p => p.EndDate.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Then do other operations:

```
// Clear list of periods
periodList.Clear();

// Add start dates which are bigger than LAST end date with NULL end date period
startDates.Where(s => s > endDates.Max())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(s => periodList.Add(new Period() { StartDate = s, EndDate = null }));

// Add end dates which are smaller than FIRST start date with NULL start date period
endDates.Where(e => e < startDates.Min())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(e => periodList.Add(new Period() {StartDate = null, EndDate = e}));

// Match other dates and add them to list
startDates.Where(s => s < endDates.Max())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(s => periodList.Add(new Period()
                                {
                                    StartDate = s,
                                    EndDate = endDates.Where(e => e > s).Min()
                                }));

// Oder period list
periodList = periodList.OrderBy(p => p.StartDate).ToList();
```

*You can test .NET Fiddle demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W4zEbd).*

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is an implementation that uses

1. a `DateRange` type and
2. sentinel values of either `DateTime.MinValue` or `DateTime.MaxValue` to "protect" any `null` first start date or any `null` last end date.

Here's the method that creates a List of `DateRange` values from two parallel lists of nullable `DateTime` values:

```
public static List<DateRange> MakeRanges(List<DateTime?> list1, List<DateTime?> list2)
{
    //Validate arguments to the function
    if (list1 == null || list2 == null || list1.Count == 0 ||
        list2.Count == 0 || list1.Count != list2.Count)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Bad arguments passed to MakeRanges().");
    }
    //If present, replace null start value of list1 with a sentinel
    list1[0] = list1[0] ?? DateTime.MinValue;
    //If present, replace null end value of list2 with a sentinel 
    list2[list2.Count - 1] = list2[list2.Count - 1] ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

    //this expression does the heavy lifting.  Match a start date with the closest non-null end-date
    return list1.Where(s => s.HasValue).Select( startItem => new DateRange{
            Start = startItem,
            End = list2.Find(e => (e.HasValue && (e > startItem.Value))).Value
        }).ToList();
}
```

Here's a DateRange class that cleans up any sentinels:

```
public class DateRange
{
    private DateTime? _start;
    private DateTime? _end;

    public DateTime? Start
    { 
        get { return _start; }
        //get rid of any sentinel value
        set { _start = value == DateTime.MinValue ? null : value; } 
    }

    public DateTime? End
    { 
        get { return _end; }
        // get rid of any sentinel value
        set { _end = value == DateTime.MaxValue ? null : value; }
    } 
    //For checking results
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}", Start.HasValue ? Start.Value.ToShortDateString() : "null", End.HasValue ? End.Value.ToShortDateString() : "null");
    }
}
```

And here's a Console App Main as a driver:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<DateTime?> list1 = new List<DateTime?>() { null, DateTime.Parse("2014-02-12"), null, DateTime.Parse("2014-06-12"), DateTime.Parse("2014-09-12"), null, DateTime.Parse("2014-11-12")};
    List<DateTime?> list2 = new List<DateTime?>() { DateTime.Parse("2014-01-12"), null, DateTime.Parse("2014-04-12"), DateTime.Parse("2014-08-12"), null, DateTime.Parse("2014-10-12"), null };

    List<DateRange> ranges = MakeRanges(list1, list2);

    //Print out results
    foreach (var range in ranges)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(range);
    }
    var pressAKeyToExit = Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output is:

```
null-1/12/2014
2/12/2014-4/12/2014
6/12/2014-8/12/2014
9/12/2014-10/12/2014
11/12/2014-null
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dates are always in order in the input list, following can be a quick solution (dont' know if it's faster):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO30229368
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string NullItem = "null";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var periodList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
            {
                new Tuple<string, string>(NullItem, "1/12"),
                new Tuple<string, string>("2/12", NullItem),
                new Tuple<string, string>(NullItem, "4/12"),
                new Tuple<string, string>("6/12", "8/12"),
                new Tuple<string, string>("9/12", NullItem),
                new Tuple<string, string>(NullItem, "10/12"),
                new Tuple<string, string>("11/12", NullItem)
            };

            var consecutiveList = GetConsecutive(periodList);
            foreach (var tupleItem in consecutiveList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", tupleItem.Item1, tupleItem.Item2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetConsecutive(List<Tuple<string, string>> periodList)
        {
            if (periodList == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("periodList");
            if (periodList.Count == 0)
                return new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

            var startList = periodList.Select(x => x.Item1).Where(y => y != NullItem).ToList();
            if (periodList.First().Item1 == NullItem)
                startList.Insert(0, NullItem);
            var endList = periodList.Select(x => x.Item2).Where(y => y != NullItem).ToList();
            if (periodList.Last().Item2 == NullItem)
                endList.Add(NullItem);

            Debug.Assert(startList.Count == endList.Count);
            return Enumerable.Zip(startList, endList, (start, end) => new Tuple<string, string>(start, end)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Although as recommended by others, it's better to model your object as a custom object (e.g. DateRange) instead of using the Tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that

1) the date intervals are in order

and

2) after each `null` endDate next startDate will be `null`

then an easy way may be to remove all intermediate `null` values.

```
List<DateTime?> startDates = allStartDates();  // excluding null values, but including the first one.
List<DateTime?> endDates = allEndDates();  // excluding null values, but including the last one.
```

Then you can make a one-to-one match to take all time-intervals. For example;

```
DateTime? startDate3 = startDates[2];
DateTime? endDate3 = endDates[2];
```

Comment: @publicgk yes seems same. I just wanted to give the algorithm, not the code. And in fact I did not examine all the codes in answers.